# Add an handler after cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I wonder if it's possible to add an handler waiting for return a cell in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

An handler like this :

```
func loadUserPicture(_width: CGFloat, _height: CGFloat, completionHandler : (_imageView:UIImageView, _image:UIImage)->())
       {
...
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to reload the previous last cell when the new one appears. Now I'm using a `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` to achieve this but I think it will be better to create an handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

and reload the previous last cell. This method gets called after the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.